# How about the converse of the property that a product of manifolds is a manifold?

Tags: manifolds

We know that the Cartesian product of two manifolds is a manifold, but is the converse true? Let us assume that we have $A$ and $B$ two second countable Hausdorff topological spaces, and $M = A \times B$. If we assume that $M$ is a $n$-manifold, with $n \geq 0$ finite, do we obtain that $A$ and $B$ are $k$- and $l$-manifolds with $k+l = n$?

Comment: Do you want any relationship between the structure of $M$ and that of $A$ and $B$? For example, $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ is a $2$-dismensional smooth manifold, and it is also the product of $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ y^2=x^3\}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}$. These two can be made smooth manifolds, but the structure of $A$ will no be induced by that of $M$. Maybe you want topological manifolds.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking about topological manifolds. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [dogbone space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogbone_space) is not a manifold but its product with $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$. This was proved in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1970322.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A21b2eed5215d8680fe42831e26d1d9a3) by Bing.

Comment: Do you know if there is any sufficient condition so that "$A$ is not a manifold" implies that "$A \times B$ is not a manifold? For example if $B = ]0,1[$ and $A$ is a cubical set?

Comment: I am not aware of such a condition.